# Installing RoR on Windows IIS 7.5 using FastCGI and Url Rewrite

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, iis-7.5, fastcgi

I'm trying to get RoR 3 installed on my Windows 7 Installation with IIS 7.5 using FastCGI.

So far, I have gotten Ruby on Rails installed and it works using 'rails server' and I can see the site on http://localhost:3000, but I want to run this site in IIS.  I have setup the FastCGI application, and have set all of the permissions (that I can think of) to allow this to work, but all I am getting is a 500 error when browsing to the IIS site

```
HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
F:\Ruby\bin\ruby.exe - The FastCGI process exited unexpectedly
```

Any ideas on how I can debug why this is happening.  When I enable Failed Request Tracing, all I see there is FASTCGI_UNEXPECTED_EXIT.  In the details of the log, I see this:

```
NOTIFY_MODULE_START
   FASTCGI_ASSIGN_PROCESS
   FASTCGI_START
   FASTCGI_WAITING_FOR_RESPONSE
   FASTCGI_UNEXPECTED_EXIT  ** This is where the error is
```

I am not sure where to begin to debug this issue, or if this setup is even supported.

Just to throw in there:  I am also trying to use URL Rewrite.  Everything I have found online already uses a rewrite to a '.fcgi' for the handler to use, but I'm not sure if this is needed for Rails 3.  If so, how is this file generated?

Answer (score 4):

You might want to try using [Helicon Zoo](http://www.helicontech.com/zoo/). It relies on the [Microsoft Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx) to do all the heavy lifting of setting up FastCGI properly.

Answer (score -2):

My recommendation: don't.  (sorry, I just had to say that)  But really, the last thing I would want to do would be to try and monkey wrench RoR into a windows box.  RoR just wasn't made for it.  Why not setup an instance in a cloud at Rackspace or Amazon?  It costs less than your internet connection at home for a simple starter instance.  Also, Amazon has a free tier so you can mess around without being charged.